# How to ask, "what's not to love?" in French

Tags: expressions

How does one ask, "what's not to love?" in French? Getting the direct translation is easy, but I feel that the whole expression isn't getting across in the French version of

> Qu'est-ce qu'il n'y a pas à aimer.

Comment: Détails sur l'expression anglaise ici : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16113/whats-not-to-love

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word-for word translation would rather be *Qu'est-ce qu'il y a à ne pas aimer ?*: it would possibly be understood but is not idiomatic.

Some equivalent rhetorical questions that express the idea that there is not much to dislike would be:

> Que trouver à redire ?
>
> Pourquoi bouder son plaisir ?
>
> Que demander de plus ?
>
> Que demande le peuple ?

Comment: Que demande le peuple ... lol ! Is there a story behind that expression?

Comment: I am sure there is... but I must confess I have used it for years without its origin... This is rather humorous nowadays.

Comment: @LukeSawczak D'après [l'Internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/14544/que-demande-le-peuple/) c'était la formule qu'employait le roi quand il recevait les doléances de ses sujets. Mais il n'y a aucune source. Pour ma part j'ai toujours cru que c'était une citation d'un empereur romain qui posait une question rhétorique : "Que demande le peuple ? Du pain et des jeux !" Il y a quelques sites web qui proposent cette interprétation. Ça ferait une bonne question à mon avis.

Comment: "Du pain et des jeux" (panem et circenses) est tiré d'une oeuvre du satiriste Juvénal, qui critiquait l'apathie et le manque d'ambition de ses contemporains. Mais il ne dit pas exactement "que demande le peuple ?" avant cette formule.